# How to securely store application files within its package folder structure?

Tags: android, security

My question is pretty general; whenever an android app accesses internal storage environment path; its folder structure is created into device's **"Android->Data->app_pakage"**.
Image files within this folder won't be viewed from gallery; which is fine.

There are lots of app which secures this files (Can't be opened directly from file manager);

Examples for this are **music apps**; they provide encoding of its downloaded files, so **it can be accessed only from that app only**. This encoding changes its extension

So my question is here, How this can be achieved?. I am looking for simplest solution, which don't require a high, complex encryption algorithms.

In-Short, **I want to prevent users to access app files from file manager- internal storage**

Comment: Try to save your folder with dot extension to hide the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this link

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Here there is detailed explanation.

To have files that can only be accessed from your app please use -

```
getFilesDir()
```

Returns a File representing an internal directory for your app.

Files saved here are accessible by only your app.